# Django CharField w/Choices, model instance needed

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Need to turn a `CharField` into a `forms.ChoiceField` in the admin.

The choices come from external API based on a model instance param. Since I need the model instance, I put the code in a `ModelForm.__init__()` method. This does not turn the `CharField` into a `ChoiceField`:

```
class OfferAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OfferAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'instance'):
            CHOICES = (
                ('A', 'Choice A'),
                ('B', 'Choice B'),
            )
            category_id = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
```

Putting the `CHOICES` and `category_id` assignment outside of `__init__()` works fine. I think I'm hitting some sort of race condition, but not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't at all understand what you want to do here, but you need to assign the field to the fields dictionary.

```
self.fields["category_id"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
```